# Starcounter - when to use fullpath namespace in JSON binding

Tags: c#, .net, json, database, starcounter

In the following example I got a warning that Item class was not found. The Batch class was fine even though it was located in the same namespace.

Did Batch work due to that it was attached in the code behind (QueueModel:Json)?

Is this by design or should it be more consistent?

```
{
   $:{DataType:"Batch"},
   BatchID:123456778,
   Name:"BatchName",
   Items: [
     {
       Message:"Hello my friend!"
     }
   ],
   $Items:{DataType:"MyCompany.Concepts.Item"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database classes lives in the same namespace as your `Json` derived class, 
then you only need to specify the class name.
If there is a code behind class (a partial class),
then you do not need to specify the `DataType` property in the json-by-example file.

So it needs to be provided either in the .json file or in the (optional) code behind class.

#### person-viewmodel.json:

```
{
   "FirstName":"Albert",
   "LastName":"Einstein",
   "Phonenumbers": [
      {
         "Type":"mobile"
         "Number":"1234"
      }
   ],
   "$Phonenumbers":{"DataType":"MyDatabaseNamespace.Phonenumber"}
}
```

#### person-viewmodel.json.cs:

```
public class PersonViewModel : Json<Person> {
}
```

So if you only use the json-by-example file (no code behind), you will need to provide the bound database type:

#### person-message.json:

```
{
   "$":{"DataType":"MyDatabaseNamespace.Person"},
   "FirstName":"Albert",
   "LastName":"Einstein",
   "Phonenumbers": [
      {
         "Type":"mobile"
         "Number":"1234"
      }
   ],
   "$Phonenumbers":{"DataType":"MyDatabaseNamespace.Phonenumber"}
}
```

Comment: Are there some pros and cons regarding where to define the data types? I see all provided examples have the "Items" definition after the Items model, but does it matter where the definition is located in the file? Could I have all datatype defintions collected in the top?

Comment: It does not matter where you put them.